# Scroll doesn't work when KeyBoardEvent keydown for arrow down key happens

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#head {
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
  tab
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 60px;
  background: green;
  overflow: overlay;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<div id='head'>Header</div>
  <div id='content'>
    <pre>
      1
      2
      3
      4
      5
      6
      7
      8
      9
      10
      11
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once head is clicked then the scroll doesn't happen on keydown. content div have `overflow:overlay` and once the focus is on it everything is fine.Is there a way to make scroll happen.

I have tried few cases like:

- on Window keydown dispatch scroll event on content div
- focus on content div

But nothing seems to work.

Another question is where it is decided that for keydown default action is scroll, Can we override it ?

code is present [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ae8k6jcf/)

Comment: I tried your fiddle and snippet, and clicked on the header, and then pressed the arrow down key: the window scrolled. Not sure what the problem/question is.

Comment: I see what you're referring to. I think that's normal behavior because the scroll bar ends where the header begins

Comment: @trincot click on the header and you will notice that the scroll within the frame will not scroll on arrow keydown

Comment: Seems to work different in Firefox. I just switched to Chrome where indeed I see what you mean.

Comment: @Josan It is a normal behaviour but my curiosity is in where is it decided that for keydown event scroll is default action and can this behaviour be overridden.

As you can see from the console log event order are in following order :
when content is clicked -
body keydown->window keydown->window scroll->body scroll->container scroll->content scroll
,when header is clicked -
body keydown->window keydown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focus on content div when head div is clicked.
Note: Focus will only work if content div have an attribute tabindex

```
<div id='container'>
<div id='head'>Header</div>
  <div tabindex='1' id='content'>
    <pre>
      1
      2
      3
      4
      5
      6
      7
      8
      9
      10
      11
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('head').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const content = document.getElementById('content');
  content.focus();
});
</script>
```

update code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zmxg09nc/2/)

Although I'm still not clear with where is it decided that for keydown event scroll is default action and can this behaviour be overridden.